# What source control is available for PHP / SQL projects

Tags: php, sql, version-control

I am working with a PHP web application that has a MS SQL back end. The development copy is hosted on a Windows server.

There will be a few developers joining me on the project, and I need some sort of source control so that (obviously) we don't over-write each other's work. But since a PHP/SQL project has to be run from the server, we can't each work with local copies and then push the updates to the server...we all have to be working on the server itself.

So I have three questions:

1. My initial thought was a simple check-in, check-out system, which should be ok for our small team of 3-4 programmers. So, what is (currently) a good program for that?
2. I also thought about each developer having his own folder in the wwwroot folder, his own full copy of the program, then pushing updates to a master copy, also on the same server. Is there a good program for doing that (file merging and conflict management)?
3. Which method do you think would be better?

Comment: I think you want GIT, it would work well with option 2, but this type of question is Off Topic for SO I am afraid

Comment: You should not be working within the live version of your software, but a development environment, which could be hooked into GIT

Comment: We ARE working with a development copy. That's all I'm asking advice on. I mentioned that in the first paragraph. I said nothing about the live deployment...not worried about that yet.

Comment: If unversed and on Windows, don't venture into the Git abyss quite yet. Try [fossil](http://fossil-scm.org/) for starters. You can migrate/downgrade later.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Run servers all your local machines. There’s lots of ways of doing this. If you’re using Laravel, it has a server built in `php artsian serve`. PHP 7 also has its own server built in.
2. Use a version control system like Git. [You can learn here](https://guides.github.com/)

Do this as soon as you can!

Sadly however, this question is not a suitable Stack Overflow question, so will be likely be closed soon. Good luck!